# Reusable background task for DAO in Room Database

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, background, android-room

Is there a way to have a reusable background task that returns value from Data Access Object in Room Persistence library?

Comment: have you looked at LiveData ? https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata

Comment: Yeah and I'm using it. What I want is when you select specific column in DAO, eg. will return String/Integer. To complete that, you need to run it from the background

Comment: you misunderstand how room works. You CAN return a List<String> or List<Integer>, when you make use of the Dao, that call simply has to be on a different thread so that it does not block the UI

Comment: Yes, I'm doing the return of List. But what if you can I want a String (Not a list of String) Is it okay to run it without background task? Thanks for the response

Comment: you can't run it without a background thread, as this blocks the UI potentially

Comment: And that is my concern, there's to many methods in my DAO and also too much Async Task to run methods. I'm looking for a way where I can create a Reusable Async Task for my background processing

Comment: "What I want is when you select specific column in DAO, eg. will return String/Integer. To complete that, you need to run it from the background" -- with RxJava, you could use `Single<String>`, `Observable<String>`, or `Flowable<String>`. See for example [the `...TripById()` methods here](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-androidarch/blob/FINAL/Trips/RxRoom/app/src/main/java/com/commonsware/android/room/TripStore.java). You should be able to use `LiveData<String>`, though I don't have an example of that. With Kotlin coroutines, you should be able to use a`suspend` function.

Comment: @CommonsWare i will try to look on that, thank you sir